# How to auto-scroll a ReactJS chat when images are uploaded and only when scrolled all the way down?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have figured out to auto-scroll a reactjs chat when **text** messages are entered and only when the scroll is all the way down or on the bottom. In other words, if a user has scrolled up, the auto-scroll will not work when new text messages arrive which is the desired outcome. However, I can not find a good solution to auto-scroll when **images** are uploaded into the chat. I have almost found a way to do so but it seems that it only works when an image is a certain height (148px including padding). The problem gets even more complex if multiple images are uploaded at the same time.

Here's the function that does the scrolling. I know it is way too complex so I hope to find a simpler solution:

```
 scrollToBottom = () => {
    
        // Get the chat's div with the "messages" id
        const messages = document.getElementById("messages");
    
     // Get the height of the new message
        const newMessage = messages.lastChild.previousSibling  
        const newMessageStyles = getComputedStyle(newMessage)        
        const newMessageMargin = parseInt(newMessageStyles.marginBottom)    
        const newMessageMarginTop = parseInt(newMessageStyles.marginTop)    
        const newMessageHeight = newMessage.offsetHeight + newMessageMargin   
        const clientHeight = messages.clientHeight       
    
    
 
// Do the first auto-scroll all the way down when the chat is first started

if (this.state.justStarted) {

//this.myRef is a div that I placed on the bottom of the chat to scroll down to

        this.myRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });

        this.setState({justStarted: false})

// I check for the number of files before scrolling down because there is a different scroll-down approach when there are multiple files.
    // You also notice that I have various conditions for the auto-scroll because as it turns out it matters what type of content is added.
    // For example, if an image is added, I need to use one of the 2nd, 3rd or 4th conditions because images have different dimensions.
    // Also, the sequence of what is added to the chat matters in my code. For example, if an image is added after text or vice versa, one of the conditions fires off.
    // I know this is complex and I do not really like it. I hope to see a simpler solution.
        

    }  else if (this.state.chatFilesLength <= 1 || this.state.chatFilesLength === null) {


     if (Math.trunc(this.myDiv.current.scrollTop) + newMessageHeight + clientHeight === this.myDiv.current.scrollHeight) {
                this.myRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });        
    } else if (Math.trunc(this.myDiv.current.scrollTop) + newMessageHeight + clientHeight + 16 === this.myDiv.current.scrollHeight) {
        this.myRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    } else if (Math.trunc(this.myDiv.current.scrollTop) + newMessageHeight + clientHeight + 20 === this.myDiv.current.scrollHeight) {
        this.myRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    } else if (Math.trunc(this.myDiv.current.scrollTop) + newMessageHeight + clientHeight > this.myDiv.current.scrollHeight) {
        this.myRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    }

}  else if (this.state.chatFilesLength > 1) {
        const number = ((this.state.chatFilesLength -1) * newMessageHeight) + (20 * this.state.chatFilesLength);
        if (Math.trunc(this.myDiv.current.scrollTop) + newMessageHeight + clientHeight + number === this.myDiv.current.scrollHeight) {
            this.myRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
        }
    }
        
    
      }
```

Chat's JSX:

```
<div className="chatArea" id='messages' ref={this.myDiv}>
                            
                       
                            {
                               
                                this.state.messages.map((message, index) => {
                                return message.body.uid === this.state.uid && !message.body.imageUrl
                                ?
                                <p className="message-sent" key={index}>{message.body.content}</p>
                                : 
                                message.body.uid === this.state.uid && message.body.imageUrl 
                                ?
                                <img src={message.body.imageUrl} className="message-sent" key={index}></img>
                                :
                                message.body.uid === "admin" && !message.body.imageUrl
                                              ?
                                              <p className="message-received" key={index}>{message.body.content}</p>
                                              :
                                              message.body.uid === "admin" && message.body.imageUrl
                                              ?
                                              <img src={message.body.imageUrl} className="message-received" key={index}></img>
                                              :
                                              null                               

                                    

                                
                                })
                            
                            }      

                            <div style={{ float:"left", clear: "both" }}
                               ref={this.myRef}>
                            </div>                     
                           
                       

                        </div>
```

And if it is of any use, here's how the scrollToBottom function is called:

```
 startChat () { 

    this.setState({justStarted: true})
       
    
    document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";       
   
    
        const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('Chats').doc(this.state.uid).collection('Messages');

        const query = ref.orderBy('timestamp', 'desc').limit(10)



        this.unsubFromMessages = query.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {                            

                            if (snapshot.empty) {

                                console.log('No matching documents.');
                                
                                firebase.firestore().collection('Chats').doc(this.state.uid).
                                set({
                                    name: this.state.displayName,
                                    uid: this.state.uid,
                                    email: this.state.email
                                }).then(console.log("info saved"))
                                .catch((error) => {
                                    console.log("Error saving info to document: ", error);
                                });
                            }
                                                  
                                snapshot.docChanges().reverse().forEach((change) => {                                  
                                  

                                if (change.type === 'removed') {
                    
                                console.log(change.doc.data().content)
                    
                                } 
                                
                                
                                else if (change.type === 'added') {                
                                
                                  this.setState(state => {
                                    const messages = [...state.messages, {id: change.doc.id, body: change.doc.data()}]
                                    return {
                                        messages
                                    }
                    
                                }, )                               
                                                              
                                setTimeout( this.scrollToBottom, 1500)                                     
                                
                                

                                } 
                                
                                else if (change.type === 'modified') { 
                                    
                                                                        
                                    const filteredMessages = this.state.messages.filter(message => message.body.allowed === "yes")

                                   this.setState(state => {
                                      const messages = [...filteredMessages, {id: change.doc.id, body: change.doc.data()}]
                                      return {
                                          messages
                                      }
                      
                                  })    
                                  
                                  setTimeout( this.scrollToBottom, 1500)
                                  
                                 
                                  
                                  } 
                    
                                                                  
                                });
                                }, (error) => {console.log(error)});             
                    
                                
    }
```

In short, I need to find a way to auto-scroll the chat when new images are added. A good solution must consider that more than one image can be added. It must always consider whether or not a user has scrolled up in which case the auto-scroll must NOT be triggered.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a much simpler and easier solution! Here it is:

```
scrollToBottom = () => {     
        
    // Messages
    const messages = document.getElementById("messages");

   // Height of the new message
    const newMessage = messages.lastChild.previousSibling
    const newMessageStyles = getComputedStyle(newMessage)        
    const newMessageMarginBottom = parseInt(newMessageStyles.marginBottom)
    const newMessageMarginTop = parseInt(newMessageStyles.marginTop)   
    const newMessageHeight = newMessage.offsetHeight + newMessageMarginBottom + newMessageMarginTop;
       
    
    // Visible height
    const visibleHeight = messages.offsetHeight    
    // or clientHeight
    const clientHeight = messages.clientHeight        
    // Height of messages container
    const scrollHeight = messages.scrollHeight 
    // How far have I scrolled?
    const scrollOffset = messages.scrollTop + visibleHeight
    
    // Inital scroll down when chat is first started
    if (this.state.justStarted) {

    this.myRef.current.scrollIntoView();

    this.setState({justStarted: false})
    

} else if (scrollHeight - newMessageHeight <= scrollOffset) {    
     this.myRef.current.scrollIntoView();
     // For multiple files    
} else if (this.state.chatFilesLength > 1) {
    if (scrollHeight - (newMessageHeight * this.state.chatFilesLength) <= scrollOffset) {
        this.myRef.current.scrollIntoView();
    }
}


  }
```

CSS

```
.message-sent {
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    max-width: 128px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 16px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #000;
}

.message-sent-image {
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    max-width: 128px;
    max-height: 128px;
    min-height: 128px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 16px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #000;
}

.message-received {
    position: relative;
    right: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 20px;     
    color: white;  

    max-width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 16px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

You might want to add CSS for message-received-image for images received in chat. You can follow the message-sent-image model with some configuration.

JSX

```
<div className="chatArea" id='messages' ref={this.myDiv}>
                            
                       
                            {
                               
                                this.state.messages.map((message, index) => {
                                return message.body.uid === this.state.uid && !message.body.imageUrl
                                ?
                                <p className="message-sent" key={index}>{message.body.content}</p>
                                : 
                                message.body.uid === this.state.uid && message.body.imageUrl 
                                ?
                                <img src={message.body.imageUrl} className="message-sent-image" key={index}></img>
                                :
                                message.body.uid === "admin" && !message.body.imageUrl
                                              ?
                                              <p className="message-received" key={index}>{message.body.content}</p>
                                              :
                                              message.body.uid === "admin" && message.body.imageUrl
                                              ?
                                              <img src={message.body.imageUrl} className="message-received" key={index}></img>
                                              :
                                              null                               

                                    

                                
                                })
                            
                            }      

                            <div style={{ float:"left", clear: "both" }}
                               ref={this.myRef}>
                            </div>                     
                           
                       

                        </div>
```